# How can I safely check is node empty or not? (Symfony 2 Crawler)

Tags: symfony, web-crawler

When I try to take some nonexistent content from page I catch this error:

```
The current node list is empty.
500 Internal Server Error - InvalidArgumentException
```

How can I safely check exists this content or not? Here some examples that does not work:

```
if($crawler->filter('.PropertyBody')->eq(2)->text()){
    // bla bla
}

if(!empty($crawler->filter('.PropertyBody')->eq(2)->text())){
    // bla bla
}
if(($crawler->filter('.PropertyBody')->eq(2)->text()) != null){
    // bla bla
}
```

THANKS, I helped myself with:

```
$count = $crawler->filter('.PropertyBody')->count();
if($count > 2){
    $marks = $crawler->filter('.PropertyBody')->eq(2)->text();
}
```

Comment: Thanks man. Your solution saved me a lot!

Comment: Checking count helped!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
$text = null;
if (!empty($body = $crawler->filter('.PropertyBody'))) {
    if (!empty($node = $body->eq(2))) {
        $text = $node->text();
    }
}

$this->assertContains('yourText', $text);
```

Comment: the empty function was still bypassed.

Comment: did not work for me neither. But using ->count() did the trick

Answer (score 26):

```
$marks = $crawler->filter('.PropertyBody')->count()
    ? $crawler->filter('.PropertyBody')->eq(2)->text() 
    : '';
```

Comment: This is the right answer, not using empty($x).

Answer (score 2):

```
try {
    $text = $crawler->filter('.PropertyBody')->eq(2)->text();
} catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e) {
    // Handle the current node list is empty..
}
```