# InvalidArgumentException: The current node list is empty. PHP-Spider (DOMCrawler Symfony)

Tags: php, symfony, web-crawler

I'm using PHP-Spider to crawl a website but when it can't find a .class it throws an error:
InvalidArgumentException: The current node list is empty.

The code is this:

```
foreach ($spider->getPersistenceHandler() as $resource) {
    echo $resource->getCrawler()->filterXpath('//title')->text().", ";
    echo $resource->getCrawler()->filterXpath("//meta[@name='description']/@content")->text()."<br>";
    echo $resource->getCrawler()->filterXpath("//div[@class='buyFooter']")->text();
    echo $resource->getCrawler()->filterXpath("//div[@class='listFooter']")->text();
}
```

on some pages the class .buyFooter exist and on others class .listFooter exist.

Is there a way to check if it exist?

I've tried isset & !empty but no luck

Comment: Have you tried with <code>->count()</code>?

check here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11846918/how-can-i-safely-check-is-node-empty-or-not-symfony-2-crawler][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11846918/how-can-i-safely-check-is-node-empty-or-not-symfony-2-crawler

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, `count()` method can be used for that, like this:

```
if( $resource->getCrawler()->filterXpath('//title')->count() )
{
    echo $resource->getCrawler()->filterXpath('//title')->text() . ', ';
}
```